# I need to pass number of arguments to a function equivalent to that of the array count of a variable

Tags: swift

I have an array variable. If the array count of the variable is 1, then I need to call a function with one argument and pass the array variable of index 0 as it's argument. If it's two, then I have to call a function with two arguments and pass the array variable of index 0 and 1 as it's arguments and so on till max three arguments.

I have tried using guard statements but I'm not sure if they will work in my case.

```
    class DFile{
//These are the functions:
        public func addData(_ date: Date) { }
        public func addData(_ date: Date, ch: Double) {}
        public func addData(_ date: Date, ch1: Double, ch2: Double) {  }
        public func addData(_ date: Date, ch1: Double, ch2: Double, ch3:       Double) {  }
    }
    //The date is static
    let df = DFile()
    var ch = [Double]() // this is the variable
    ch.append(GetNumber()) //I append data to the variable
    df.addData(dt,ch1: ch[0], ch2: ch[1], ch3: ch[2])// I need this to be dynamic, it needs to be different according to the array count.
```

Expected output: if array.count = 2,
df.adddata(_ date: Date, ch1: Double, ch2: Double)

Comment: Why not just have one function that takes an array and then only make use of the first three values?

Comment: You should either make `addData` take an array or make it [variadic](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166)

Comment: If you insist on staying with the 4 functions, then `switch ch.count { case 0: addData(dt) case 1: addData(dt, ch: ch[0]) case 2: addData(dt, ch1: ch[0], ch2: ch[1]) case 3: addData(dt, ch1: ch[0], ch2: ch[1], ch3: ch[2]) default: break }`

Comment: The addData functions are in another swift file and thus I cannot change them. I did try the switch statements. Thanks a ton for that. Is there any other shorter way to make it work?

Comment: Why not add the switch code to a function that takes an array as argument in an extension to that DFile class. It should make the rest of your code cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed with creating a separate method in **`DFile's extension`** that will handle the calling of respective `addData` methods, i.e.

```
extension DFile {
    func addData(_ date: Date, _ ch: [Double]) {
        switch ch.count {
        case 0:
            self.addData(date)
        case 1:
            self.addData(date, ch: ch[0])
        case 2:
            self.addData(date, ch1: ch[0], ch2: ch[1])
        case 3:
            self.addData(date, ch1: ch[0], ch2: ch[1], ch3: ch[3])
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Call `addData(_:_:)` in `extension DFile` like,

```
df.addData(dt,ch)
```